# SPI not working on ATtiny441

Tags: microcontroller, avr, spi

I've been tearing out my hair for a while on this.  I'm just trying to do a basic SPI transaction -- sending one byte -- on the [ATtiny441](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8495-8-bit-AVR-Microcontrollers-ATtiny441-ATtiny841_Datasheet.pdf) but I'm getting nothing on the SCK and MOSI lines.  First, here are my fuse settings and pinout (in red):
[image: Extended fuse bits]
[image: High fuse bits]
[image: Low fuse bits]
[image: Pinout]
Probably the most useful information here is that I'm using the 8MHz internal oscillator, and not dividing by 8. Note that I'm remapping the SPI pins so that I can leave my logic analyzer on while programming with the default pins.

Here's my `main.c` file:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define SCK         3
#define MOSI        1
#define CSN         2

uint8_t data = 0;
uint8_t reg = 0;


int main(void)
{
    PRR = 0; // turn off power reduction
    REMAP |= (1<<SPIMAP); // remap SPI pins
    // set SCK, MOSI, CSN as outputs:
    DDRA = (1<<SCK) | (1<<MOSI) | (1<<CSN); 
    // enable SPI, set as master, use f_clkIO/16 (500kHz):
    SPCR = (1<<SPE) | (1<<MSTR) | (1<<SPR0);
    reg = SPSR;
    reg = SPDR;

    while(1)
    {
        PORTA &= ~(1 << CSN); // clear CSN
        SPDR = data++; // send byte
        while( !(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)) ); // wait for flag to set
        PORTA |= (1 << CSN); // set CSN
        _delay_ms(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm reading the `SPSR` and `SPDR` registers before the `while` loop at the recommendation of Atmel's [AVR151](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2585-Setup-and-Use-of-the-SPI_ApplicationNote_AVR151.pdf) app note (page 11).

When I run the code the `CSN` line stays low, along with `SCK` and `MOSI`, suggesting that it's getting stuck in the `while( !(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)) );` section waiting for the `SPIF` to set.  When I comment out this line, the `CSN` line goes low for ~25us then back high, which is expected.  I tried manually setting the outputs high on `SCK` and `MOSI`, too, to make sure it's not a pin connection problem and they worked fine.

**Question:** Does anyone see the error in my ways?  I feel like there's one small, stupid error somewhere.

**Edit:** I also want to mention that I tried it with and without the clock divider (by 8) fuse bit set, and with and without remapping the SPI pins from the default location (i.e. programming, removing programming leads, attaching logic probe leads).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see any obvious bug in your code. But some suggestion for testing: check if SPI module is activated and takes over the pins at all -- either different SPI mode with high idle clock, or set pin high before enabling SPI and check it goes down. Checking compiled code is a good idea too (it is short enough to disassemble and check "by hand"), maybe some strange/buggy optimization or error in your headers for ex.? Btw. I assume you see no activity on data and clk lines neither with while line commented out, right?

Comment: @Martin I was afraid of that, but thanks for the good troubleshooting advice!  I'll certainly try those.  And that's correct -- there's no activity on SCK or MOSI with that `while` line commented out.

Comment: @Martin Figured it out!  Check out my answer if you're interested.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka!  Turns out the `SPIMAP` bit is incorrectly mapped!

```
/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/avr/include/avr/iotn441.h:377:0: note: this is the
location of the previous definition
 #define SPIMAP 0
 ^
```

(It should be bit 1.) Therefore, the line remapping the SPI pins was failing!  This is corrected by placing a `#define SPIMAP 1` in the `#define` section.

**EDIT:** As Martin pointed out, I am indeed using an old version of avr-libc.  I was using the latest version of [CrossPack](https://obdev.at/products/crosspack/index.html), which is dated back almost 4 years from today.  The newest version has this bug fixed.

Comment: Good you have solved it. Just FYI this bug does not seem to be present in (at least) more recent libraries from Atmel, namely version 3.6.0 from late 2016 is fine (http://distribute.atmel.no/tools/opensource/Atmel-AVR-GNU-Toolchain/3.6.0/avr-libc.tar.bz2). The date string in this output you have copied here is bit strange anyway, as according to the Atmel's changelog support for ATtiny441 was added only as late as 2016. So it is maybe worth to consider updating headers and libs before you get stuck with other strange bug ...?